# Windows Event Viewer Error Code After Crash

Tags: windows, crash, event-log

> Error code 10000050, parameter1 e60c0000, parameter2 00000001,
>   parameter3 bf04963f, parameter4 00000001

I have a computer that is repeatedly blue screening and this is the only error in the system logs that seemed abnormal.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: choose the best answer and accept it, only it was useful for u

Comment: neither of those answers helps unfortunately, i had already tried all of the suggested remedies.  And yes I did google this first and found the exact same thing, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: may be try re-installation of your windows will be nice

Comment: It's a work computer and I was told I can't do that, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all your drivers are up to date. Also, some simple googling would have revealed that this error tends to come from sound drivers on XP systems.

Answer (score 0):

it seems not here is right place to ask this question but here we brought some useful info to you:

1. Scan your computer for viruses. Virus activity can affect DLL (Dynamic Link Library) files that control how the video card functions.
2. Download the most up-to-date drivers for your video card. Drivers are dependent on your video card manufacturer, either ATI or Nvidia.
3. Click "Start" then type "Memory" in the search bar. The Windows Memory Diagnostic tool should be the only option. Click on it and select the "Restart Now and Check for Problems" option. If serious errors continue, you'll have to replace the random access memory (RAM) in your computer.